# DRF: Using URL parameters to determine ordering on nested serializer fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

My question is whether there is a way to use filters given by the user in the URL to order a queryset using nested serializers using the nested fields.

For example:

```
class EventsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Events
        fields = ['date', 'location']
        

class GuestsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    events = EventsSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Events
        fields = ['name', 'phone', 'seat_no', 'events']
        

class GuestEvents(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = GuestsSerializer
    name_param = self.kwargs['name']
    order_param = self.request.query_params.get('orderBy')
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        data = Guests.objects.select_related('events').filter(name=name_param)
        return data
        
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        res = super(TestData, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        res.data = {"guestevents":res.data}
        return res
```

If i have these serializers and view in order to show what events a guest is attending and the ordering is by default ascending based on the date; is it possible to have the user type location as the orderType and have that be used for ordering or can i not make use of thee 'location' field at this point?

Comment: [`ordering_fields`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#specifying-a-default-ordering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRF has OrderingFilter which can help you:

```
filter_backends = [filters.OrderingFilter]
ordering_fields = '__all__'
```

Declare this in your view and specify fields which you want to order by. Then you can do that using ?ordering=name etc.

More info on that: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter